# How to check what additional props were passed into a react component that were not defined?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm wondering if it's okay to access the defined PropTypes in the React component class, by using: `this["__proto__"]["constructor"]["propTypes"]`

For example if I have this component:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    name: string
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this["__proto__"]["constructor"]["propTypes"]);
    return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>;
  }
}
```

A use case would be that if I want to check what additional props were passed into the component that were not explicitly defined.

To be clear, the above DOES WORK, it's more a matter of whether or not this is something that should be avoided - I know this is probably a somewhat opinionated question, but I haven't seen it anywhere else so, thought I'd look for some feedback. If it should be avoided is there a better way?

Comment: I think you should post this question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I would not depend on `propTypes`. If you want to see what props exist for a component, I recommend [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) so you can drill down and see what props exists on particular components.

Comment: @3Dos Please, get to know what is acceptable on Code Review before redirecting questions there. This one is too hypothetical and centered around generic best practices to be on topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing object prototype directly using [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is not recommended because this property has never been part of the ECMAString standard. Main vendors *did* implement it and these days it will likely work in all the environments targeted by your React app.

Usual replacement for it is [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) method which you could use same way:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.propTypes
```

But in any case, you can read static properties of the class directly:

```
render() {
  console.log(Hello.propTypes);
  return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}!</h1>;
}
```

Prefer this better.

Comment: I didn't think to use `Hello.propTypes`, I was trying `this.propTypes` which was obviously `undefined`. I agree, this is 100% better. Thank you! And thank you for providing a rationale as well!